# How to Create a PHP menu with a Recursive Method?

Tags: php, list, recursion, foreach

I'm creating a recursive menu which shows a year and an issue number. Somehow, it's just printing once for each array element.

This is what I need:
**Please select a year -> 2013 -> Issue#1, Issue# 2, Issue# 3, Issue# 4**.

And what Im getting is:
**Please select a year -> 2013 ->Issue#1**

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
echo "<div id='cssmenu'>";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Please select a Year</span></a>";
echo "<ul>";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('/usr/apps/webdata/backend/assets/newsletters/temp');
$list = array();
foreach($dir as $file)
{
    if ($file->isDot()) {
        continue;
    }

    $string = $file;
    if (preg_match_all("#(\d{1,})#", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
        foreach($matches as $match)
        {
            $issue = $match[0];

            while (list($key, $value) = each($match)) {
                //YEAR
                if (strlen($value) == 4) {
                    $uyear = $value;
                    //echo "Year: $uyear \n";
                }
                // ISSUE#
                elseif (strlen($value) == 1) {
                    $uissue = $value;
                    //echo "Issue: $uissue \n";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!isset($list[$uyear])) {
        $list[$uyear] = array();
        echo "<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>" . $uyear . " </span></a>";
        echo "<ul>";
    }

    if (!in_array($uissue, $list[$uyear])) {
        $list[$uyear][] = $uissue;
        $a = count($uissue);
        for ($i=0; $i<$a; $i++) {
            echo " <a class=fancypdf href='#' onclick=myPDF('".$file."')> Issue# ".$uissue."   </a>";
            echo "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</li>";
    }
}

echo "</ul>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
////IM USING THIS PRINT JUST TO VERIFY IF THE FUNCTIONS GOES THROUGH ALL THE ELEMENTS
print_r($list);
?>
```

***UPDATE***
I was able to find the issue; my recursive function was not right, and that's why it was printing just the first element. However, I don't know how to actually print the second element.

```
$a = count($uissue);
for($i=0;$i<$a; $i++)
{
    echo " <a class=fancypdf href='#' onclick=myPDF('".$file."')> Issue# ".$uissue."   </a>";
    echo "</li>";
}
```

Probably using a For-Each function? I'm still trying to figure this out.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `$string` is going to be?  My guess is your regular expression is not correct.

Comment: My string is:
/usr/apps/webdata/backend/assets/newsletters/temp/Newletter_2013_1.pdf
From which my function extracts the year and issue#, which is right, but when i tried to output this answer it doesnt do it